# Doubt in the proof of Theorem 6.4 in Rudin, Functional Analysis, 1973

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, topological-groups, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ a vector space and $(Y, \tau)$ a topological vector space such that $Y \subset X$. Consider $W \subset X$ such that $Y \cap W \in \tau$.  If $f \in Y \cap W$, I have to prove that there exists an $\delta > 0$ such that $f \in (1- \delta) W$.

Edit 1: W is a convex and balanced set, that is, $\lambda W \subset W$, for all $|\lambda| \leq 1$.

Edit 2: Y is a vector subspace of $X$.

I don't know if this is true. This doubt appeared while I was studying the proof of Theorem 6.4 in Rudin, Functional Analysis, 1973. There, I think he takes $X = C^{\infty}_0(\Omega)$, $(Y,\tau) = \mathfrak{D}_K$ and $f = \phi - \phi_i$ : [image]

Comment: Intuitive idea for an approach: $Y\cap (1-\delta)W=(1-\delta)(Y\cap W).$ If there is no such $\delta,$ then $f$ is, intuitively, on some edge of $Y\cap W.$ Since $Y\cap W$ is an open set, you want to prove it can't have any points like this.

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I just added an Edit to my question.

Comment: What means an edge of $Y \cap W$ ?

Comment: The edge of $Y \cap W$ is defined by $(\text{cl }Y \cap W )\backslash (\text{int } Y \cap W)$.

Comment: Basically, it seems like if $U\in \tau,$ and $v\in Y,$ the set $$V=\{r\in\mathbb R\mid rv\in U\}$$ is open in $\mathbb R.$ Then in your case, since $1\in V,$ then $1+\epsilon\in V$ for some $\epsilon>0,$ and $\delta =1-\frac1{1+\epsilon}=\frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}$ works. So ou just need to prove $V$ is open in $\mathbb R.$

Comment: @Thiago That's why I said "intuitively." Edge here is just an intuitive term.

Comment: Basically, the map: $p:r\to rv$ is a continuous function from $\mathbb R$ to $Y,$ and $V=p^{-1}(U)$ is open because $U$ is open and $p$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you Thomas, perfect solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a topological vector space $Y$ over $\mathbb R,$ for any $v \in Y,$ the function:

$$p_v:\mathbb R\to Y, r\mapsto rv$$

is continuous, where $\mathbb R$ is given the standard topology.

So let $U=Y\cap W \in \tau$ and $f\in U.$ Then, by continuity $V=p_f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\mathbb R$ and contains $1.$ So there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $1+\epsilon \in V.$

Setting $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon},$ then $1-\delta=\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}.$

Since $p_f(1+\epsilon)=(1+\epsilon)f\in U,$ $$f=(1-\delta)(1+\epsilon)f\in (1-\delta)U.$$

So $f\in(1-\delta)U\subseteq (1-\delta)W.$

---

We could break this into a lemma without any reference to $W$:

> **Lemma:**
> If $Y$ is a topological real vector space and $U\subseteq Y$ is open, and $u\in U,$ then there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $u\in(1-\delta)U.$

Comment: Perfect! I think this will help many people who is studying by Rudin's book.

Comment: You really only need $p_v$ continuous for each $v\in Y,$ you don't need the combined continuity of scalar multiplication, $\cdot:\mathbb R\times Y\to Y$ nor the continuity  of addition: $+:Y\times Y\to Y.$ Neither of these is used in the proof.

Comment: I liked your Lemma, very nice.